# Database user permission vs where parameter

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, blazor-server-side

For example in the cosmos database i can set the permission like this:

```
new PermissionProperties(
                    id: "SomePermissionId",
                    permissionMode: PermissionMode.All,
                    container: "Container1",
                    resourcePartitionKey: new PartitionKey(123))); //Id of the Tenant
```

Also in the sql query i can add a where parameter to the sql query like this:

```
... WHERE a.tenantId = "123"
```

I wonder why would i use the first approach in a server-side .net App. Are there any security downsides for the second apprach?

thanks.

Comment: This is a bit vague, can you provide more context on your goal? If you're asking about implementing multitenancy, I discuss one approach using partitioning in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tht_RV5QPJ0

Comment: @NoahStahl saw you video before your comment. How do you query your database for each tenant? Do you use the permission by db user like in my example (so the permissions automatically makes sure you get only the results for a certain partition) or do just add a "where" parameter to your query?

Comment: I don't use the Cosmos permission system at all, just use the partition key parameter on queries in the SDK. In this model the app layer is responsible for access control, not the database layer.

Comment: @NoahStahl yes another way to do it with a similar idea. I just wondered if it may have some security issues along the way. We use the azure ad and read the tenantId from the profile. I have seen many videos / blogs where the tenants are separated on a higher level. Some even use a separate database und separate app and manage it with devops / azure resources.  I wonder why so many go the long way if it is easier this way.

I mean, this way we do it, we need to trust the partitionKey variable. 

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9t4_OHXprA

Thanks for your time. Appreciate it!

Comment: I think there are many approaches that can work. The partition key strategy relies upon securely binding the allowed partitions to the user's session identity and using that as the source during a query. Will that work for all scenarios? Probably not, just one to consider :).